# What is the Maven idiom for accessing configuration files?

Tags: java, maven

For example suppose I'm using the standard project structure and have

src/main/config/config.xml

To access this I presume

```
new File("src/main/config/config.xml");
```

would be incorrect

Comment: For the general question you have asked, I don't think there is a Maven standard per se. It would be more a question of general config file locations. And whether they're on the file system or the classpath would be determined by what the file is for and how you want it to be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "Maven Idiom" for accessing configuration files.  Maven is a build platform, not an execution platform.  So the conventions for accessing configuration files that apply are really just the conventions of the Java platform that you are using; e.g.

- the plain J2SE way of doing it, or
- the J2EE and/or webapp way of doing it, or
- the J2ME way of doing it, or
- ...

Maven only comes into the picture because you (presumably) have resource files in your project / version control that need to be included in the JAR or WAR or whatever artifacts that you are building.  To get this to work in Maven, you simply need to understand how Maven copies non-Java files into the artifacts.

- In the simple (JAR) case, the default behavior is to copy anything in `src/main/resources/` into the JAR, with the same relative name; e.g. `src/main/resource/foo/bar.xml` becomes `/foo/bar.xml` in the JAR file.
- For WAR files, the default is to copy anything `src/main/webapp` to into the WAR file.  So if you wanted a file to be accessible in the webapp as a classpath resource with the name `/foo/bar.xml` you would put it in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/foo/bar.xml`.  (I'm assuming that you know how webapp classpaths work ... or that this isn't your use-case.)

Comment: +1, but `src/main/resources` is a perfectly valid place for classpath resources in a WAR project, too.

Answer (score 1):

A config file is just a resource on your classpath like any other, so use:

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource("config.xml");
```

You'll need to do the usual `Use as Source Folder` on your `src/main/config` folder for this to work in Eclipse with m2e.

Answer (score 1):

I think config files should be in **src/main/resources** by default.